# Do I need to tell Apache Tomcat to keep a Websocket connection open?

Tags: tomcat, websocket

I am trying the [Apache Tomcat Websocket Implementation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/web-socket-howto.html). The Problem is, that the connection always gets closed after at most 30 seconds of idle time.

Do I need to configure Tomcat so that it  keeps the connection open?
If so how can I do that?
I tried to set up the connectionTimeout in the Connector element of the server.xml for the HTTP protocol. That had no effect, but I don't know if it just doesn't work because I didn't adjust the protocol attribute to something websocket specific (since I don't know what that protocol declaration looks like).

Or is it perhaps a client-side problem.

Thanks for helping,
Leo

**edit:** This Problem has been solved with Tomcat 7.0.28 ([Bug Description](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53074), [changelog](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tomcat has [several issues](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Tomcat-WebSockets-issues-and-workaround) with WebSocket, and one of them is it close the connection after 20 seconds (this is the connectTimeout value in server.xml). Increase that value to workaround the issue.

-- Jeanfrancois

Answer (score 4):

I manage to get the websocket open infinitely. All you need to do is to set the `connectionTimeout` in the `server.xml` of Apache to minus one (`connectionTimeout="-1"`). That solved my problem. :)
ref:

Comment: As you can see in my question, the problem has been solved in 7.0.28, and websocket should by default be open inifinitely.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to keep the connection open, ping the client/server. This is the only way to reliably ensure that there is something at the end of the connection.

The internet is not a reliable transport, so it's worth ensuring that your code can handle disconnects.

Comment: will this increase the load of the server?

Answer (score 0):

SET IN SERVER.XML

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="999999"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: I tried that (see second paragraph of my question), have you actually tried it yourself with a websocket connection?

Answer (score 0):

apart from connectionTimeout setting in server.xml, another reason could be your websocket message implementaton class as well. getReadTimeout method is one which is used to set websocket timeout in milliseconds. for example, if you want to set socket timeout 2 minutes (2*60*1000) than you may use below code.
Note: you can set infinite timeout (always open) by returning -1.

```
@Override
public int getReadTimeout() {
    return 2*60*1000;
}
```

For complete implementation, Refer this sample code in my answer.
[tomcat websocket servlet listening port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836806/tomcat-websocket-servlet-listening-port/20739008#20739008)