# websocket port on tomcat

Tags: http, tomcat, websocket, tcp, port

Does each browser client WebSocket create separate/new port on the Tomcat server for bidirectional, full-duplex communications, or do all browser clients use a single port on the Tomcat server for communication?

Comment: No. The single HTTP port (and the HTTPS port if configured) is/are used for everything. Clients can't create new ports on servers.

Comment: Duplicate of [tomcat websocket servlet listening port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17836806/tomcat-websocket-servlet-listening-port)