# Tomcat websocket closes connection

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I run simple websocket server on Tomcat:

```
package server.ws;

import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;




@ServerEndpoint("/websocketendpoint")

public class WsServer {

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(){
        System.out.println("Open Connection ...");
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(){
        System.out.println("Close Connection ...");
    }

    @OnMessage
    public String onMessage(String message){
        System.out.println("Message from the client: " + message);
        String echoMsg = "Echo from the server : " + message;
        return echoMsg;
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Throwable e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Client that connects to my server complains regarding `Tomcat` closes session after echo was transmitted. How to make the server to not close the connection after echo?

Comment: is your problem similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/10497746/5313017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not sure, but i guess `onMessage`has no return value.
for me, the following code works fine and i have any problems

```
@OnMessage
public void message(final String message, final javax.websocket.Session session) throws IOException {
    for (final Session s : session.getOpenSessions()) {
        final Basic endpoint = s.getBasicRemote();
        endpoint.sendText(message);
    }
}
```